# C# Storing and using control characters in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am storing ASCII data file layout settings (row delimiter, column delimiter, text qualifier, etc) in a SQL Server table.  One of the columns in the table contains the column delimiter (comma, tab, etc).  Currently, I am storing the delimiter as ',', '\t', '|', etc.  The problem is when I retrieve the value from SQL Server to my C# application using SqlDataReader the .Net framework always adds the escape character to the value.  This is a problem when the delimiter is already stored as "\t".  I end up with "\\t".

Then when I try to use the column delimiter value in String.Split() it doesn't work because the character separator ends up being interpreted as {"\\t"} or {'\',\t'}.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server does not use escape characters. If you want to store a tab character, you must use the correct ANSI character (`char(9)`), not `'\t'`.

Comment: Storing the '\t' in SQL Server doesn't seem to be the problem.  When i query the table in SQL Server management studio it returns the correct value.  Its not until I retrieve the value from within the my C# .Net application that the problem occurs.  Thats when the extra '\' is added.

Comment: What do you mean by "it returns the correct value"? Are you saying that SSMS shows `\t`?

Comment: Sorry.  I get it now.  Your right. I replace '\t' with char(9) in the Sql Table and it works.  Many thanks.